# Why is my Button hidden when using CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a simple Activity with a `CollapsingToolbar`. Let me show you what I have 1st and then explain what the problem is!

> When the toolbar is collapsed (left) vs when it is expanded (right)

[image: collapsed Toolbar] [image: expanded Toolbar]

As you can see, the `Search button` doesn't show when the toolbar is expanded. How can I fix this?

> activity_search.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_search" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> content_search.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/etIngredients"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/search"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvIngredients"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btSearch"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried searching for this question, but could'nt find anything at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hidden due to your collapsable toolbar. When you say match_parent it takes height excluding the height of expanded toolbar. All you need to do is add bottom_margin of expended toolbar height.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Makes sense!  I'll try this when i get back to my pc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your `content_search.xml` thus:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/etIngredients"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvIngredients"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/search"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And if you don't need to have your search button right at the bottom of the screen, move it above the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: When i full up the recyclerView, the search button goes below the screen again. If i don't find a fix,  I'll put the search button on top like you suggested

Comment: I would suggest keeping the search button just below the `EditText` if you want the button to search for the text entered in the `EditText`. However, if you _have to_ keep the button at the bottom, you can make the layout more complicated and use a `FrameLayout`. Let me know if you would like me to demonstrate it.

Comment: Never worked with FrameLayout, but Neo's suggestion worked. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1):

Please check your content_search.xml

what is id `android:layout_below="@id/ll"`??

i think this is id of linear layout, please add this and run hope it will help you.

Comment: Edited my question. It's the first LinearLayout :)